# Can we use the matrix exponential trick to solve the Frenet-Serret frame?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, frenet-frame

The Frenet-Serret frame has the following property:

$$\begin{bmatrix}T'\\N'\\ B'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\kappa&0\\-\kappa&0&\tau\\0&-\tau&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}T\\N\\B\end{bmatrix}$$

I have learnt that we can usually solve O.D.Es of this form as follows $v'(s)=Mv(s)\implies v=\exp(Ms)\times v_0$ if $M$ is a matrix. But I hesitate to say that we can do that here, because my second thought, after this being my first, was that both $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are functions of $s$, the arc length, so they also change as $s$ changes so the matrix $M$ would be in flux...

Would it still be correct to write $v=\exp(Ms)\times v_0$, where $v$ is $\begin{pmatrix}T\\N\\B\end{pmatrix}$?

Or is there some other trick to solve this system for all future $s$, once the base position $v_0$ is known?

Comment: In general, the equation $v'(s)=M(s)v(s)$ does not have the solution $v=e^{Ms}v_0$. This is because when $M=M(s)$, differentiation and diagonalization cannot be interchanged. The matrix $Z$ you need is $v(s)=Z(s)v(0)$, called the [matrizant](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix) and in general will not have a nice closed form. If it so happens that $[M(s),\int^s ds' M(s')]=0$, then one has something like $Z=\exp(\int^s ds' M(s'))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general "trick" is the following. Consider an ODE of the form:
$$
x'(s) = M(s)x(s), \ \ \text{given }x(0)
$$
where $M(s)$ is a matrix. You can solve this problem by the integrating factor technique. Just multiply the whole equation by $\exp\left(\int_0^s -M(r)dr\right)$:
$$
\exp\left(\int_0^s -M(r)dr\right)x'(s)-\exp\left(\int_0^s -M(r)dr\right)M(s)x(s) = 0
$$
And notice that this resembles the product rule of the derivative:
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\left(\exp\left(\int_0^s -M(r)dr\right)x(s)\right) = 0
$$
which can be solved by integrating from $0$ to any $s'$:
$$
\int_0^{s'} \left(\frac{d}{ds}\left(\exp\left(\int_0^{s} -M(r)dr\right)x(s)\right)\right)ds = \exp\left(\int_0^{s'} -M(r)dr\right)x(s') - \exp\left(\int_0^0 -M(r)dr\right)x(0) = 0
$$
or equivalently:
$$
x(s) = \exp\left(\int_0^s M(r)dr\right)x(0)
$$
Note that if $M(r)=M$ a constant matrix, then $\exp\left(\int_0^s M(r)dr\right) = \exp(Ms)$ which is what you tried before. In general you need to compute the integral of $M(s)$.

(See the comments for some technical care one need to have when using this reasoning)

Comment: This does not work in general cf. comment to original post. Counterexample: $M(t)=\left[\matrix{t & -t \\-1 & 1}\right]$. By applying this method, we get an answer in terms of exponentials of powers of $t$, while the correct solution is in terms of the error function $\operatorname{erf}$. See eg. *Advanced mathematics* by Prosperetti

Comment: Interesting... in the case of the matrix you mentioned, what makes the integrating factor argument above fail? I mean, its very straightforward. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: I mean, if you plug in the solution with the exponential of powers of t, that seems to satify the ODE. Is this a problem of uniqueness?

Comment: Good question! If we expand the matrix exponential $e^{\int\limits^s ds' \ M(s')}=\sum\limits_n \left[ \int\limits^s ds' \ M(s')\right]^n/n!$. When we take the derivative $d/ds$ on each term, we *expect* to get something like $n M(s)\left[ \int\limits^s ds' \ M(s')\right]^{n-1}$, from which we can show the candidate solution solves the ODE. And there's the problem: if $M(s)$ and the integral of $M$ don't commute, that's *not* the result of differentiating.

Comment: Oh! Very interesting. I wasn't aware of that! You are totally right. Thanks. I will leave my answer here (with some notes), in case someone else makes the same mistake.